# ILGenerator.DeclareLocal() takes a type of a class not yet compiled

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, cil, reflection.emit

Toying with making a compiler for my own language, I'm trying to generate some MSIL code using the Reflection.Emit framework. It works fine when using `int` when I declare local variables. However, when I want to declare a local variable of a type I have not yet compiled I get into trouble since the `DeclareLocal()` takes a `Type` as argument. That is my uncompiled class, say `A`, still needs to be defined using

```
 assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
 module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(Filename); 
 module.DefineType(name, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class)
```

So how will I ever be able to compile the following program

```
class A {
    void M() { B b = new B(); }
}
class B
    void M() { A a = new A(); }
}
```

Comment: @phoog: he might as well wait for someone to do his work, then..

Comment: Im not actually doing C# here..  it was just an example of circular dependency

Comment: Languages often require that a declaration is known before usage.  Pascal and C++ are good examples.  If you don't want this restriction then you'll need to create a multi-pass compiler.

Comment: @Hans Im not sure how this would be possible using the Reflection.Emit framework. I need to generate a class such that I can refer to its TYPE, when doing calls and assignment. But with circular definitions as above none of the two classes will ever be fully constructed before the other.

Comment: You can fix it by generating the code for a type when you encounter it and it isn't emitted yet.   You may end up nesting several levels deep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary insight you need here is that `TypeBuilder` derives from `Type`. So, even if you didn't finalize a type yet (by calling `CreateType()`), you can use it to declare a local variable in another type.

One more barrier I encountered is that `GetConstructor()` on an unfinished `TypeBuilder` doesn't work (it throws an exception). But if you create the default constructor explicitly, you can call it through the `ConstructorBuilder`.

```
static void Main()
{
    var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        new AssemblyName("foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
    var module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("foo.dll");
    var aType = module.DefineType(
        "A", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
    var bType = module.DefineType(
        "B", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
    var aCtor = aType.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
    var bCtor = bType.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
    CreateMethodM(aType, bType, bCtor);
    CreateMethodM(bType, aType, aCtor);
    aType.CreateType();
    bType.CreateType();
    assemblyBuilder.Save("foo.dll");
}

static void CreateMethodM(
    TypeBuilder thisType, Type otherType, ConstructorInfo otherCtor)
{
    var method = thisType.DefineMethod(
        "M", MethodAttributes.Private, typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);
    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    var local = il.DeclareLocal(otherType);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, otherCtor);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, local);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

Comment: Argh! My solution is so close to yours! I was blinded by wanting to call "t.DeclaringType" rather than simply "t"

Comment: `DeclaringType` is something different, it represents the type this type was declared in, for example when it's a nested type.